# PHP overwrites object without it being used [edited]

Tags: php, html, arrays, object, overwrite

Alright, I was put on hold because it wasn't clear what I am asking, so let me rephrase. I have this variable:

```
$town->streets
```

I declare it like so:

```
$town->streets[$i] = new street;
$town->streets[$i] = (Object)newStreet();
```

Of course I do it inside a for loop.
The newStreet() function generates a random number of houses for the street, each house has some attributes, such as type, tenants, is it a shop or library, what items there are inside if so, and so on. Right afterwards I echo the attributes of shop type houses to see if they are different.

As intended, every shop has different attributes. Now, right afterwards I have *some code* and after that I do the same echoing for houses again. However now each shop is the same as the last shop of the array, meaning that it somehow got overwritten inside *some code*. I am not accessing the houses, but am modifying other variables inside the streets. Yet I don't know why the houses and shops are getting overwritten.

The code does its task, meaning that cores and streets are distributed as I wanted to, so there are no actual errors, the objects' structure has never been a problem before, even though I have multiple objects structured like this. I am also aware that putting an object in a variable just creates a reference to it (or so I was told), but I still don't see why it is partially modified when I am not even accessing those parts at all.

*some code* is as follows:

```
$town->cores[0] = new core;
    $town->cores[0]->id = 0;

    for($i = 0;$i < $streetnum;$i++){
        if($town->streets[$i]->start == -1){
            $cid = round(mt_rand(0,count($town->cores)-1));
            $town->streets[$i]->start = $cid;
            if(count($town->cores) > 1 && round(mt_rand(0,10)) > 8){//PICK EXISTING CORE
                $ends = $town->cores;
                unset($ends[$cid]);
                $town->streets[$i]->end = $ends[array_rand($ends,1)]->id;

            }else{//NEW CORE
                $town->streets[$i]->end = count($town->cores);
                $town->cores[$town->streets[$i]->end] = new core;
                $town->cores[$town->streets[$i]->end]->id = $town->streets[$i]->end;

            }

        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: What is this? `$town->streets[$i] = new street;
        $town->streets[$i] = (Object)newStreet();` overwriting?

Comment: In the first piece of code `$town->streets[$i] = new street; $town->streets[$i] = (Object)newStreet();` - the second will overwrite the first which seems a trifle odd.  Also, the nested loop will then repeat the same thing

Comment: @AbraCadaver (and RamRainder)  Yes, I am declaring the variable to then write into it. If you look at the output I wrote at the very end, you will see what the problem is. The overwriting must happen after $town->cores[0] = new core; $town->cores[0]->id = 0; these lines, I just have no idea where and why.

Comment: $town->cores[$town->streets[$i]->end]->id = $town->streets[$i]->end;

That looks funky to me. $obj->array[]->object-node thats basically what you have done on that line. You can set an array into an object but im not sure you can then use the array within the object as you have.

Comment: @Chris I have multiple objects with similar or the same structure, and it has never been a problem yet. The cores and streets are distributed as I intended, so the code itself works, I just don't know why parts of the street objects are modified that I'm not even accessing.